# Read http header in qt webengine

Tags: http-headers, qtwebengine, qtwebview

I want to capture server http response in qt demo browser and check the header fields. How to implement this using qt webengine?
I also saw QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor but using this class we cant read http header fields.

Answer (score 0):

you need to run your browser with remote debug to enable chrome dev tools:
set 'QTWEBENGINE_REMOTE_DEBUGGING' = port , in QT environment . 
after that from other qtwebengine instance connect to localhost:port ,
then you can use all chromium dev tools ,monitor/manipulate all network traffic .

If you do not need visualization ,
then need to make your own client for chromium dev tools protocol(they have pretty good manuals) .
Collect all responses in way you prefer , in responses look for method='Network.responseReceived' , with available selector (for example response['params']['response']['url'] ) , then you will have in you response response['params']['requestId']  , with requestId you can do 
Network.getResponseBody(requestId=response['params']['requestId']) .

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But i want to read http headers in qt source code. For example, i want to add a method in demo browser that print http headers of all requests. There is no need to capture traffic or any tools as dev tools or wireshark.

Answer (score 0):

I think is not possible.
You can use a QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor to intercep your requests.
Here I'm adding a bearer token for all requests, but I think is impossible to read headers

```
    void customInterceptor ::interceptRequest(QWebEngineUrlRequestInfo &info)
{
  info.setHttpHeader("Authorization", ("Bearer " + m_token).toLocal8Bit());
  info.setHttpHeader("accept-language", Translator::instance()->getCurrentLang().toLocal8Bit());
}
```